# Check if input std::array pointer data is equal to some constant array

Tags: c++

I have a function trace that can be simplified to :

```
void foo(const std::array<unsigned long long int, 3>& in)
```

And I want to check if the value of in is specifically something (eg. `{1,1,1}`) so I can warning/error.

I've seen that you should be able to use `==` and `!=` operators in `std:array`, however the following fails:

```
if(in.data() == std::array<unsigned long long int, 3>{1,1,1})
```

because:

> error: no match for `‘operator==’` (operand types are ‘`std::array<long
>   long unsigned int,::const_pointer` {aka `const long long unsigned int*`}’
>   and ‘`std::array<long long unsigned int`,’)

I get that `.data()` seems to be returning a `cosnt_pointer`, but I do not know how to fix this to do what I want. How can I do this comparison (aside from a naive for loop, which does not seem very C++y)?

Comment: Drop the `data()` call, it returns pointer to underlying storage, but you want to compare actual contents of both arrays. It should be simply `if(in == std::array<unsigned long long int, 3>{1,1,1})`

Comment: @Yksisarvinen right, duh. I am more used to C, so I saw the `&` in the input and I assumed `in` was a pointer of some sorts. ah. my mistake

Comment: yeah, `&` is a bit overused. It inherited all meanings from C and additionally denotes a reference (if used when declaring a variable). And then there's `&&`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in` refers to a `std::array<unsigned long long int, 3>`, `std::array<unsigned long long int, 3>{1,1,1}` is also a `std::array<unsigned long long int, 3>`, hence you can compare them directly via `==`:

```
if(in == std::array<unsigned long long int, 3>{1,1,1})
```

In case the array has more elements you might want to use an algorithm to avoid creating the second array. Something along the line of (not tested):

```
if (in.end() == std::find_if(in.begin(),in.end(),[](auto x){ return x != 1; }))
```

If there are only three elements I would probably simply write

```
if (in[0] == 1 && in[1] == 1 && in[2] == 1)
```

Comment: other versions with less typing include `in == decltype(in){1,1,1}` and `in == std::array{1ull,1ull,1ull}`

Comment: @M.M Imho the most readable is `in[0] == 1 && in[1] == 1 && in[2] == 1`. it isnt necessary to create a second array

Comment: @idclev463035818 actually, you are right in that comment.